# How to remove extra td on colspan reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a table which contains td with colspan. Whenever I add colspan to a row, there is an additional or excess added cell.

```
 const RenderTD = ({row}) => {

  return table.cols.map(col => (
    <td key={col} 
      colspan={row == 1? 2 : 1}>{col}</td>
  ))
 }
```

here is the sample code: https://jsfiddle.net/e7gnd1tf/

How can I remove these?

Answer (score 0):

1. Dont create components inside another component. Or use memoization
2. Td should be wrapped in tbody
3. Use key prop
4. The excess cell is being created because when you add colspan to a cell, it merges that cell with the next cell, effectively removing the next cell from the table. However, in your code, you are still creating that next cell, even though it has been merged with the previous cell. To fix this issue, you can conditionally render the extra cell only if colspan is not used, like this:

```
const RenderTD = ({ row }) => {
  return table.cols.map((col, index) => (
    <React.Fragment key={col}>
      <td
        colSpan={row === 1 && index === 0 ? 2 : undefined}
        rowSpan={row === 2 && index === 0 ? 2 : undefined}
      >
        {col}
      </td>
      {index === 0 && row === 3 && <td></td>}
    </React.Fragment>
  ));
};
```

In the above code, the extra cell is only rendered if colspan is not used and the row is the third row (row === 3) and the column is the first column (index === 0).